# Determine a variable by function parameter

Tags: javascript, function

I was wondering if you could "combine" a variable and function parameter? If so, how could you do it?

E.g.

```
var word1 = 1;
var word2 = 13;
var word3 = 3;

function magicFunction (magicParameter) {
  //something magical happens here
  return magicVariable; //"word" + magicParameter somehow
}

magicFunction(1) = 5; //word1 = 5
magicFunction(2) = 13; //word2 = 13
magicFunction(3) = 3; //word3 = 3
```

Thanks!

**Update**: You are able to do this with `eval()`:

```js
var word1 = 5;
var word2 = 13;
var word3 = 3;

function magicFunction (magicParameter) {
  var magicVariable = eval("word" + magicParameter);
  return magicVariable; //"word" + magicParameter somehow
}

console.log( magicFunction(1) ) //word1 = 5
console.log( magicFunction(2) ) //word2 = 13
console.log( magicFunction(3) ) //word3 = 3
```

Comment: There is word variable inside combine function. is that expected behavior

Comment: `{magic}` ?????

Comment: @Venkatraman No, it could be anything. {magic} just stands for anything that allows you to "combine" the two things.

Answer (score -1):

here magic value is `+`

```js
var word1 = 1;

function combine (index) {
  magicVariable = word1 + index;
  
  return magicVariable;
}

console.log(combine(1));
```

Comment: is what you want magician ?

Comment: Could you expand on that? That outputs "2" not `word1`

Comment: @ChrisHappy because word1 is variable not string .  if we used `"word1"+index` then output would be `word1`